# Jaeger All in one docker gRPC issues

Tags: docker, jaeger

Getting this error when i startup jaeger allinone docker latest. Not sure why this is - can anyone help here? I am running this on Windows, Docker for desktop. This is behind a corp proxy, if that's helpful. This is the command i am using to startup

```
docker run --name jaeger -e COLLECTOR_ZIPKIN_HTTP_PORT=9411 -p 14250:14250 -p 5775:5775/udp -p 6831:6831/udp -p 6832:6832/udp -p 5778:5778 -p 16686:16686 -p 14268:14268 -p 9411:9411 jaegertracing/all-in-one:latest
```

---

```
jaeger_1 | {"level":"warn","ts":1614280472.7859962,"caller":"grpc@v1.29.1/clientconn.go:1275","msg":"grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {:14250 0 }. Err: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing failed to do connect handshake, response: \"HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request\\r\\nConnection: close\\r\\n\\r\\nBad request\"". Reconnecting...","system":"grpc","grpc_log":true}
jaeger_1 | {"level":"info","ts":1614280472.7862206,"caller":"grpc@v1.29.1/clientconn.go:1056","msg":"Subchannel Connectivity change to TRANSIENT_FAILURE","system":"grpc","grpc_log":true}
jaeger_1 | {"level":"info","ts":1614280472.7865677,"caller":"grpc@v1.29.1/clientconn.go:417","msg":"Channel Connectivity change to TRANSIENT_FAILURE","system":"grpc","grpc_log":true}
jaeger_1 | {"level":"info","ts":1614280472.786733,"caller":"grpc/builder.go:119","msg":"Agent collector connection state change","dialTarget":":14250","status":"TRANSIENT_FAILURE"}
jaeger_1 | {"level":"info","ts":1614280473.7868812,"caller":"grpc@v1.29.1/clientconn.go:1056","msg":"Subchannel Connectivity change to CONNECTING","system":"grpc","grpc_log":true}
jaeger_1 | {"level":"info","ts":1614280473.7870724,"caller":"grpc@v1.29.1/clientconn.go:1193","msg":"Subchannel picks a new address ":14250" to connect","system":"grpc","grpc_log":true}
jaeger_1 | {"level":"warn","ts":1614280473.9255273,"caller":"grpc@v1.29.1/clientconn.go:1275","msg":"grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {:14250 0 }. Err: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing failed to do connect handshake, response: \"HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request\\r\\nConnection: close\\r\\n\\r\\nBad request\"". Reconnecting...","system":"grpc","grpc_log":true}
jaeger_1 | {"level":"info","ts":1614280473.925584,"caller":"grpc@v1.29.1/clientconn.go:1056","msg":"Subchannel Connectivity change to TRANSIENT_FAILURE","system":"grpc","grpc_log":true}
jaeger_1 | {"level":"info","ts":1614280475.517604,"caller":"grpc@v1.29.1/clientconn.go:1056","msg":"Subchannel Connectivity change to CONNECTING","system":"grpc","grpc_log":true}
jaeger_1 | {"level":"info","ts":1614280475.517681,"caller":"grpc@v1.29.1/clientconn.go:1193","msg":"Subchannel picks a new address ":14250" to connect","system":"grpc","grpc_log":true}
jaeger_1 | {"level":"warn","ts":1614280475.6554408,"caller":"grpc@v1.29.1/clientconn.go:1275","msg":"grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {:14250 0 }. Err: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing failed to do connect handshake, response: \"HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request\\r\\nConnection: close\\r\\n\\r\\nBad request\"". Reconnecting...","system":"grpc","grpc_log":true}
jaeger_1 | {"level":"info","ts":1614280475.6555314,"caller":"grpc@v1.29.1/clientconn.go:1056","msg":"Subchannel Connectivity change to TRANSIENT_FAILURE","system":"grpc","grpc_log":true}
jaeger_1 | {"level":"info","ts":1614280478.3234975,"caller":"grpc@v1.29.1/clientconn.go:1056","msg":"Subchannel Connectivity change to CONNECTING","system":"grpc","grpc_log":true}
jaeger_1 | {"level":"info","ts":1614280478.3236346,"caller":"grpc@v1.29.1/clientconn.go:1193","msg":"Subchannel picks a new address ":14250" to connect","system":"grpc","grpc_log":true}
jaeger_1 | {"level":"warn","ts":1614280478.5104907,"caller":"grpc@v1.29.1/clientconn.go:1275","msg":"grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {:14250 0 }. Err: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing failed to do connect handshake, response: \"HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request\\r\\nConnection: close\\r\\n\\r\\nBad request\"". Reconnecting...","system":"grpc","grpc_log":true}
jaeger_1 | {"level":"info","ts":1614280478.5105915,"caller":"grpc@v1.29.1/clientconn.go:1056","msg":"Subchannel Connectivity change to TRANSIENT_FAILURE","system":"grpc","grpc_log":true}
jaeger_1 | {"level":"info","ts":1614280481.8225894,"caller":"grpc@v1.29.1/clientconn.go:1056","msg":"Subchannel Connectivity change to CONNECTING","system":"grpc","grpc_log":true}
jaeger_1 | {"level":"info","ts":1614280481.8227663,"caller":"grpc@v1.29.1/clientconn.go:1193","msg":"Subchannel picks a new address ":14250" to connect","system":"grpc","grpc_log":true}
jaeger_1 | {"level":"warn","ts":1614280482.031132,"caller":"grpc@v1.29.1/clientconn.go:1275","msg":"grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {:14250 0 }. Err: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing failed to do connect handshake, response: \"HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request\\r\\nConnection: close\\r\\n\\r\\nBad request\"". Reconnecting...","system":"grpc","grpc_log":true}
```

Comment: Why not ask the images' [author](https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger)?